# retrieving something from an sqlite database as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have retrieved an integer from the currency column in my sqlite database. Then I want to add that integer to a variable in my program then put that integer back into the database.
However, the problem is I can't get the retrieved variable to become an integer? Instead it's a tuple and I can't seem to remove the brackets around it.
This is my code so far.

```
c.execute("SELECT currency FROM userinfo WHERE userId=?", (uid,))
storedcurrency=c.fetchone()
storedcurrency = re.sub("{|}|'|,|(|)|", '', storedcurrency)
storedcurrency = int(storedcurrency)
updatedcurrency = score + storedcurrency
```

Comment: Could you not get the integer from the tuple?

Comment: I tried that with `storedcurrency = int(storedcurrency[0][0])` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Just use one [0], since there is only an int in a tuple.

Comment: You don't need to remove the brackets, you can just index your tuple to retrieve the element you want.

Comment: Show what `storedcurrency` is as retrieved with `c.fetchone()`.